# Upgrading my jenkins server

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to upgrade my Jenkins server using version 2.89.2, to version 2.107.3.  Below are the specs of my system

CentOS 6.8
Java version "1.8.0_45"

I tried to upgrade manually using the instructions [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/upgrade-jenkins-and-plugins)

After starting Jenkins, I get hit with the error

```
`Error
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only 1.0 is supported as <?xml 
version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <?xml 
version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) 
at 
org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDeclWithVersion(MXParser.java:2608)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseXmlDecl(MXParser.java:2592)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parsePI(MXParser.java:2466)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1447)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
atcom.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.jav    a:109)
Caused: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only 1.0 is 
supported as <?xml version not '1.1' (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <? 
xml version=\'1.1\'... @1:19) `
```

Seems like Jenkins is hardcoding 1.1 version to config.xml.  One workaround solution is to directly edit that config.xml to make change

from: `<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>`
To:   `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`

I've read that roll backs are not supported, Is there any other way I can avoid having to use 1.0 version?   I can't seem to get Jenkins started without switching from XML Ver 1.1 to 1.0

Answer (score 1):

The switch to 1.1 was in [Jenkins 2.105](https://jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.105), so you should not be affected by that message when *upgrading* Jenkins

Check the logs to make sure that the Jenkins starting is indeed a 2.107 one.